To read all the row records using case statement and to display 1 or 0 based on some condition
There is table A with some unique records and a column from A matching with a key value in table B. And I need to display 1 if table B has a specific record in a row with status 1 to be considered in a case statement in select query.
I tried using MAX(case… but, it fetches only the max of the column whereas there is a possibility of other lower values which may also have status as 1.
Could you please help me with the script?
For ex.
Table A:
Col1     Col2    Col3
Abc      Test1   Test2
Def      Tst1    Tst2
Ghi      Tet1    Tet2

Table B:
Col1     Col2    Col3
Abc      123     1
Abc      343     0 
Abc      012     1
Def      343     1
Def      123     1
Def      012     0 

So from the above tables, I need the below output which I’m unable to obtain.
Col1      Status1     Status2     Status3
Abc       Active      Disabled    Active
Def       Active      Active      Disabled

I’m trying to check the condition based on case statement like,
Max(case when col3 = 1 and col2 in (123, 012) then Active end)
But this is returning only the max of col2.
But not checking the other rows.
I’m trying to run a query in MS SQL,

It's not clear what the columns status1,status2,status3 are derived from. Please add the query you have so far.

FYI case is an expression not a statement.

I'm not sure TableA is involved; it looks like a pivot of TableB only. The problem is there's no column to denote the order of those values (the order you expect doesn't match the ordering of any of the columns).

Does this answer your question? Goup by column and multiple Rows into One Row multiple columns (you just need to define your order as 343 is not less than 012 and greater than 123; it's greater than both.)
